# Reduce vibration transferred from outboard motor to aluminum boat

Tags: vibration, boat

I have a new [2.5 hp Mercury outboard motor](https://www.mercurymarine.com/en/ca/engines/outboard/fourstroke/25-25hp/) on a used 12-foot aluminum boat. When I use the motor, it vibrates the boat and everything in it, which makes a lot of noise.

I'm doing what I can to eliminate rattles *inside* the boat:

- Tightening loose aluminum boat parts, applying caulking to trim, etc.
- Securing loose items in the boat, such as the [oarlock horns](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/29169/boat-motor-rattles-oarlock-horns).

But I want to limit the vibrations that get transferred from the motor to the boat in the first place.

What can I do to reduce the vibrations? The motor is brand new, so it shouldn't have any mechanical issues causing extra vibrations.

---

Photos:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks as though the back portion has a rubber pad sandwiched between the boat and another sheet of aluminum ... is that an accurate assessment?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Good question. It looks to me like the black stuff is rubbery caulking wrapping a solid inner core, such as wood, plastic, etc. Maybe the purpose of the solid core is to make the transom thicker and stronger for mounting the motor, not reducing vibration. I'm reluctant to peel away the caulking to investigate since that would compromise the seal. I've sent a message to the previous owner to ask what he did there. Hoping to get a reply.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It looks like it's plywood: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u11Wi.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a portion of a [mud guard](https://www.princessauto.com/en/mud-guards/product/PA1000001707?skuId=8685117) to pad the motor from the boat. And I used plastic caps from juice containers to spread out the force from the clamps so that the clamps don't damage the rubber.

[image]

[image]

The installation went smoothly. But to be honest, it's hard to tell if it's reduced the vibration much.

Answer (score 1):

A contact at a marine supply company said:

> One thing you might try is raising that motor up off the transom maybe
> by ½” if possible.   We have found that the bracket actually sitting
> on the transom produces noise.